# using asp.net membership provider how to check if the user is registered or not?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, membership, provider

using asp.net and c# membership provider how to check if the user is registered or not?
I want to handle this in code not by using "login status"?

Comment: Please reiterate. If the user is logged in, and CAN login, then they must be registered. If the username is already taken, the register control already checks for that. So specify a bit more.

Comment: @BBetances - sorry I was not clear in my question,what I meant is checking if the user is logged in or anonymous,thanks,it works now

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not sure if you want to know if they are a "registered" user or have logged in (as the Login status would indicate)

Here's to know if they are logged in (what the Login status uses):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

Comment: thanks man , yes I was not clear in my question sorry, and your solution works fine :)

Answer (score 12):

```
MembershipProvider.GetUser(string username, bool updateLastActivityDateTime)
```

This will get you the user, or return null of the user does not exist (has not been registered)